# Read string from shared memory C++ POSIX

Tags: c++, string, posix, shared-memory

In my other question one user help me with send string by shared memory. But when I try to receive this data program says `Core dumped`. I try this code:

```
key_t lineKey = ftok("/tmp", '1');
int sharedLine = shmget(lineKey, sizeof(std::string), IPC_CREAT | 0666);
std::string *line = (std::string *)shmat(sharedLine, NULL, 0);

sem_t *reader1_sem;
reader1_sem = sem_open("reader1_sem", O_CREAT, 0666, 0);

while (1) {
    sem_wait(reader1_sem);
    std::cout << (*line);
}
```

I tried also rewrite this to `char *` but it not working too (`char *line = (char *)shmat(...);`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot place an `std::string` on shared memory; The pointers that are stored internally in this object are not meaningful outside the running process.

The C++ committee envisioned at some point that you ought to be able to use a shared-memory allocator that would use relative pointers (e.g. maybe [see here](https://rawgit.com/google/cxx-std-draft/allocator-paper/allocator_example_offset_pointer.html)):

```
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, magic_allocator<char>>
```

However, this is hampered by the unspecified nature of standard library implementations; the Standard does not actually mandate that standard library classes that use allocators also use allocator pointers internally. (I think this is [LWG 1521](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1521).)

Comment: So I should use `shmget(lineKey, 100, IPC_CREAT | 0666);` and after this use `line` as `char *`? I try but it not working too.

Comment: @ventaquil You need De-/Serialization like with having a file. `std::string` cannot be De-/Serialised directly.

Comment: @ventaquil: If you don't fancy delving into C++11 allocators and offset pointers, you can either try and make sense of [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/interprocess.html) which tries to do some of this for you, or stick with raw data in the shared memory without any indirections.