# Running non-default constructor from class-overloaded new operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I want a class `Watchdog` to create its objects in POSIX shared memory.

Keep in mind source code for this class is compiled into a static library and the source code for the methods are actually placed in a c++ source file.

My first attempt at this was having a `static Watchdog* createWatchdog(param p1, param p2, ...)` function in my class, and use this as a wrapper for allocating the memory of the object, then calling a placement `new (ptr) Watchdog`.

This worked fine but then I remembered the `new` operator could be overloaded so I came up with this solution:

> Watchdog.h

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace og {

class Watchdog {
public:
    Watchdog();
    Watchdog(const std::string t_name, void* t_data, const size_t t_datSize);

    static void* operator new(size_t count, const std::string t_name, const size_t t_datSize);


protected:
    Watchdog(const Watchdog&) = delete;
    Watchdog& operator=(const Watchdog&) = delete;

private:
    std::string m_name;
    void* m_data;
    size_t m_datSize;

    // and other member variables
}; // end class Watchdog

} // end namespace
```

> Watchdog.cxx

```
#include "Watchdog.h"

using namespace og;

Watchdog::Watchdog()
{}

Watchdog::Watchdog(const std::string t, void* t_data, const size_t size)
{}

void* operator new(size_t count, const std::string t_name, const size_t dat)
{
     int fd;
     void* obj;

     // removed all error checks for the sake of the example
     fd = shm_open(t_name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_EXCL | O_RDWR, 0600);
     (void) ftruncate(fd, sizeof(Watchdog));
     obj = mmap(0x0, sizeof(Watchdog), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
     (void) shm_unlink(t_name.c_str());

     return obj;
 }
```

> CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 2.6 )
PROJECT( WATCHDOG C CXX )

SET( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
SET( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED OFF)

SET( watchdog_HEADERS
 Watchdog.h
)

SET( watchdog_SRC
 Watchdog.cxx
 ${watchdog_HEADERS}
)

SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "-g3 -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic")

ADD_LIBRARY( watchdog STATIC ${watchdog_SRC} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( watchdog -lrt )
```

Compiled with `cmake . && make`

> main.cxx

```
#include "Watchdog.h"

using namespace og;

int
main()
{
    Watchdog* W;

    W = new ("test", 20) Watchdog;
}
```

---

1. **Compiling with `g++ main.cxx -L. -lwatchdog -lrt` raises that linkage error**:

`` /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/9/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDncNvb.o: in function `main':
main.cxx:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `og::Watchdog::operator new(unsigned long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

---

2. **Do I have to initialize all member variables by hand in the operator new method**? 
   I know I can do `return ::operator new (sz)` or `return ::operator new(sz, ptr)` from the operator new method but I fail to see how I can call instead a non-default constructor (such as the second one in the class specification).

Comment: If you overload `operator new` you also *need to* overload `operator delete` to properly deallocate the memory when `delete` is called.

Comment: I also don't see how your `operator new` satisfies the requirements of an allocation function. It is supposed to return a pointer to the beginning of a memory block of at least `count` bytes, different for each invocation of `operator new` (as long as previously returned values have not been deallocated with `operator delete`).

Comment: @uneven_mark Added exact reproducible example.

Comment: @uneven_mark Yep I'm aware I also need to overload the delete operator. As for the requirements of an allocation function, the error checks I've suppressed will throw if provided `t_name` corresponds to an already used shared memory object. The user will be aware that he has to chose a different name for each object he desires to create. There shouldn't be the need for multiple of these objects in a single program.

Comment: Fundamentally flawed approach if you want this to apply to your string data as well. What are you actually trying to do, and why?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the plan is to have that object allocated from shared memory so it can be fully accessed from another process which has been forked thereafter. Though I don't get what string data you're mentioning

Comment: @SpectreVert The data that is owned by the `std::string`. You know it's dynamically allocated, right? By the `std::string`? It doesn't live in your class.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're right. Are pointers and manual initialization from the Watchdog::operator new method the only way to have normally dynamically allocated objects respect the model I need?

Comment: @SpectreVert No it is currently impossible to use `std::string` through process boundaries, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582558/read-string-from-shared-memory-c-posix). You may want to try [boost.interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) instead. It has container types (including a `string`) usable across shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1:

Your definition

```
void* operator new(size_t count, const std::string t_name, const size_t dat) //...
```

in `Watchdog.cxx` defines a free user-defined `operator new`, not the class-specific overload, that you declared in the class `Watchdog`.

Instead use:

```
void* Watchdog::operator new(size_t count, const std::string t_name, const size_t dat) //...
```

Since the class-specific overload is chosen for the *new-expression* in `main`, its definition will be missing.

---

Question 2:

`operator new` only returns a pointer to raw memory. It is not responsible for constructing objects in it.

Objects are constructed by the *new-expression* with a call to a constructor as necessary. The syntax follows that of variable definitions. For example

```
W = new ("test", 20) Watchdog;
```

calls the default constructor for the `Watchdog` object, while

```
W = new ("test", 20) Watchdog(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

will try to call a constructor overload matching the three arguments.

The first parameter list in the *new-expression* is not used as arguments to the constructor, but as arguments that the allocation function needs in order to provide the correct pointer to memory in which the object can be constructed.

---

Also note, that the `operator new` should allocate memory for (at least) `count` (first argument) bytes. This argument will be provided with the correct value required to construct the object by the *new-expression*. This is in particular important when you are using the array versions of `operator new` and `new`.

---

Also be aware that you are constructing only the `Watchdog` object *itself* in the shared memory provided by your `operator new` overload. Should your class use `new` to allocate memory for e.g. the `void* m_data` member, it will not use your `operator new` for the allocation, but the regular allocation function, which will allocate (as usual) in the processes (unshared) memory space.

The same applies to memory allocated by non-trivial members of your class, such as `std::string m_name`. When it is going to need to allocate memory (if SSO is insufficient), it will allocate the memory for the string data with the regular allocation function (in unshared memory), not your `operator new` overload.

This means, for example, that `m_name` cannot be safely used from the other process you are sharing memory with.

Comment: Alright I see where I was misunderstanding things: placement parameters are **not** passed in the same way as constructor arguments. Thanks.

Comment: @SpectreVert I have added another comment, expanding on LightnessRacesinOrbit's comment on the design. I agree that this approach is probably not what you want.